# How to structure one to optional to many database?

Tags: sql, schema, relationship, one-to-many, option-type

I am creating a website for a newspaper. All of its articles have one section, and most articles are directly under their section: `/section_name/article_name`. However, there are some articles which are not directly under their department—they are under a subsection: `/section_name/subsection_name/article_name/`. How would I structure this database, where not all articles are under a subsection?

My initial thought was to have `ONE Section has MANY Subsections has MANY Articles`. But then how would I take care of the "optional subsection" problem?

One solution would be to have two relationships: `ONE Subsection has MANY Articles` and `ONE Section has MANY Articles`. This way, an article can be in both a section and a subsection. However, this does not seem intuitive to me; `Subsection` is not related to `Section` at all? Is there any other solution?

Just another note: an article is requested with the following parameters: `/:section_name(/:subsection_name)/:article_name`, where a colon marks a parameter, and parentheses mark an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The way you yourself suggest, but add a foreign key from subsection to section.
2. Establish a default or 'main' subsection for every section, so all articles are linked only to a subsection.
3. Use a single section/subsection table, with a 'parent section' column.  This would allow section/subsection nesting to any depth, which you might want to control with application rules.

EDIT:
In the third approach, the section/subsection table will have a foreign key into itself.  If not null, that foreign key identifies a parent section.  This structure can represent a tree of subsections of any width or depth, and articles could be associated with any section in that tree.  This type of structure may be overkill for the simple scenario you outlined, but is flexible enough to accommodate some expansion of your conceptual model without having to change the physical structure.

Comment: Could you explain your third solution a bit further?